# call the function with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have in class A:

```
-(void)threewaysbuttonshow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@" Do something ");
}
```

and in my class B I want to call my function which is threewaysbuttonsho in class A.

I am thinking to use NSNotificationCenter. here is my code bellow in class B, but it doesn't call my function when the code run, any help appreciate.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(threewaysbuttonshow:) name:@"something" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addObserver:selector:name:object:` call needs to be in Class A and then in Class B you need to post the notification. Like so:

```
@implementation ClassA

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init] 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(threewaysbuttonshow:) name:@"something" object:nil];
    return self.
}

// Remove the observer once the instance is deallocated.
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)threewaysbuttonshow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@" Do something ");
}

@end
```

Do not forget to remove the observer in dealloc, otherwise `NSNotificationCenter` will call the instance after it has been deallocated and crash your app.

You post a notification like from Class B:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"something" object:self userInfo:nil];
```

This will make `NSNotificationCenter` call the all the methods register for the notification with the name `something`.